# How to wrap function call that sometimes does async call to make it behave synchronously

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I have a function which logic is:

```
    _setDataChunk: function (action) {
        var self = this;
        /* some code */
        var data = self._getDataChunk(action);
        populateWidget(data);
    }
```

`GetDataChunk` sometimes has an AJAX call inside, sometimes not. How to wrap `_getDtaChunk` function to force it act synchronously all the time?

Comment: You need to share the `_getDataChunk` method skeleton. You can use callback method or use promises

Comment: Does `_getDataChunk` has callback function, if so - use it, if not - make two functions that does not have such inconsistency.

Comment: The first "A" in AJAX is for "asynchronous". My advice is to accept that Javascript is a medium that frequently uses asynchronicity. Don't force it into a different paradigm.

Comment: What you are trying to do is impossible. You can however do the inverse: force it to act asynchronously all the time, and deal with that.

Comment: also, if the function really is sometimes async it cannot possibly return the desired data into `var data` unless what you're actually getting back is a Promise.

Answer (score 1):

Don't - make your code act as it were always asynchronous instead.

Assuming (for example) that the reason you don't want to fetch is because you already have the data:

```
function _getDataChunk(params) {
     if (!cachedPromise) {
         cachedPromise = $.ajax(...);
     }

     return cachedPromise;
}
```

and then use the Promise:

```
_setDataChunk: function (action) {
    this._getDataChunk(action).then(populateWidget);
}
```

See also the first five slides of http://www.slideshare.net/RayBellis/memoizing-withindexeddb which shows how to cache asynchronously calculated results

Comment: Data is sometimes static and available instantly sometimes it is fetched by ajax, I have no power over how the ajax call looks, I am not the one invoking it directly.

Comment: Protip: Just cache the promise, not the result `data`. It simpler and avoids parallel requests.

Comment: @Bergi Indeed, and that's what I did in those slides (but forgot) - I've updated appropriately (which gives a cleaner answer, too)

Comment: @Yoda can you show the implementation of the current `_getDataChunk` function ?

Answer (score -1):

You can force the ajax request in `_getDataChunk` to run in sync mode.

You will need to change the function to something like this:

```
function _getDataChunk(action, forceSync) {
    var forceSync = (typeof forceSync !== 'undefined') ?  forceSync : false;
    ...
    $.ajax({
        ...
        async: !forceSync,
        ...
    });
}
```

And when you call `self._getDataChunk`, add `true` to the call:

```
self._getDataChunk(action, true)
```

Comment: It's an automatic response to anyone that ever recommends `async: false` - doing so is _never_ justified

Comment: when the question is "how force it act **synchronously** all the time" - a downvote on correct answer is wrong...

Comment: It might be true, but if the answer is correct (based on the wrong question) I don't think it deserves a negative score.

Comment: If an answer advocates bad practise, then IMHO it does

Comment: I don't have any power over AJAX in the `_getDataChunk(action);`

Comment: If you don't have any power over ajax in _getDataChunk then I guess you also can't return the call and use the promise... do you know if the call there is done by jQuery or not?